# dpkg: error processing package liboobs-1-5 (--configure)

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I am not able to install any package. I am getting the following error:

```
dpkg: error processing package liboobs-1-5 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 liboobs-1-5
```

When I try to remove or repair, I get the same error. So, what should I do now?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the *complete* output of `sudo apt install --reinstall liboobs-1-5`

Comment: And show `lsb_release -rc` please.

Comment: Please also add output of `apt-cache policy liboobs-1-5` to the question.